# Properties that hold almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $u$ some measurable function. If $v$ is a function and $u=v$ a.e.; when is true to say that $v$ is measurable?

Also let P be some property, and $f$ & $g$ measurable functions and that property P holds for $f$ a.e..  If $f=g$ a.e.; when is true (if ever) to say that P holds for $g$ a.e.?

Any feedback on these two questions are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is $v$ any arbitrary function satisfying $u=v$ a.e.?

Comment: I would think that the answer to both questions is "always", isn't it? This assumes the domain and range of the functions is always the same (e.g., always mapping $X\rightarrow Y$), so it makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Equality $u=v$ a.e. means that $v$ is equal to $u$ outside a set of measure zero, a null set. For $v$ to be measurable you need not just this null set to be measurable, but also any of its subsets. They may not be, and then $v$ may not be measurable. For example, take $u=0$ everywhere, and $v=0$ everywhere except on a non-measurable subset of a null set, where $v=1$. Then $u=v$ outside a null set, but $v$ is non-measurable.

However, the original $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and the measure $\mu$ can always be [completed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure#Construction_of_a_complete_measure) by adjoining subsets of null sets and assigning measure $0$ to them. Function $v$ becomes measurable in the completion.

Your second statement is correct assuming $f$ and $g$ are measurable. That $f$ has property $P$ a.e. means it has it outside of a null set, and $f=g$ a.e. means $g$ is equal to $f$ outside of another null set, so $g$ has $P$ outside the union of those two null sets, which is also a null set.

However, one has to be careful with the meaning of "property" here, above "$f$ has $P$ a.e."  means "$f(x)$ has $P$ for $x$ outside a null set". Being positive is an example of $P$ that  works. Being continuous or smooth, on the other hand, is not such a property. The key difference is that smoothness and continuity at $x$ can be altered without changing the value at $x$, they depend on behavior of $f$ at multiple points around it.

Lebesgue spaces like $L^1$ are designed to deal with such properties. Technically, their elements are not functions but equivalence classes of functions up to equality almost everywhere. When someone says that an $L^1$ function is continuous a.e. for example, they  mean that the class of functions equal to $f$ a.e. has a continuous a.e. representative.

Comment: great answer! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but I don't get your response to my 2nd question and don't think it is right. As if you consider $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebguese measure; then as $\lambda(\mathbb{Q})=0$, we have $1_{\mathbb{Q}}=0$ a.e.. But the constant function $0$ is continuous a.e. and $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is continuous nowhere! So this does not agree with what you are saying or am I not understanding you correctly. Please can you clarify things for me and if I am wring please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: @Jens: See my edit

Comment: Thanks with your edit I see it now. Just one more thing to clear up in the 1st part of your answer, so if $v=1$ on some non empty set $A$ then if $A$ is not measurable then $v$ won't be measurable since $\{v>0\}=A\notin \mathcal{A}$; so only when the $\mathcal{A}$ is complete, will we be sure $v$ is measurable? Thanks again.

Comment: @Jens Assuming $A$ is a non-measurable subset of a null set, yes.